# How correctly check if input is not equal zero

Tags: javascript

I have simple code, in input user inputs number and it must print the numbers until the input is not equal to zero.

And the problem is when i submit value, page stops responding

Here is how my code looks like:

```js
 window.onload = function() {
    
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
    
    function printInput() {
     var output = document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0];
     var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value;
    
      while(input !== 0) {
         var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value;
      output.innerHTML += input+'<br>'; 
     }
    }
     btn.addEventListener('click', printInput);
    
    }
```

```html
  
     <input type="text" class="input" maxlength="1">
     <button class="btn">Submit</button>
     <div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value property of input is a string.

You must compare with the correct type:

`while (input !== '0')`

or

`while (input != 0)`

----- edit -----

Consider changing the `while` to an `if`, otherwise it will print any number different of 0 indefinitely.

```js
 window.onload = function() {
    
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
    
    function printInput() {
     var output = document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0];
     var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value;
    
      if(input !== '0') {
         var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value;
      output.innerHTML += input+'<br>'; 
     }
    }
     btn.addEventListener('click', printInput);
    
    }
```

```html
  
     <input type="text" class="input" maxlength="1">
     <button class="btn">Submit</button>
     <div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks i don't know why i decided to use while loops for this easy thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes

- Change `type` attribute from `text` to `number`
- Change from `while` to `if`

**Demo**

```js
window.onload = function() 
{
  var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
  function printInput() 
  {
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0];
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value;
    if (input !== 0) 
    {
      var input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value;
      output.innerHTML += input + '<br>';
    }
  }
  btn.addEventListener('click', printInput);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="input" maxlength="1">
<button class="btn">Submit</button>
<div class="output"></div>
```